# How to switch focus to browser popup using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I need to accept a web browser popup which comes on refreshing the website.
I have used following script to refresh the web site -

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("all_bt")).SendKeys(Keys.F5);
```

After that I used below code to accept the web browser popup.

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    alert.Accept();
```

But I am getting error as Alert not found.
I believe the focus is not on the popup, that may be the reason.
Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: try directly click on ok .. if still not work then check if there is any frame present .. it must a application pop-up besides brower pop-up .. switch to alert won't work in that case

Comment: On directly clicking OK button it is working. On recording the script the popup is recognized as ->  <tr>
 <td>assertAlert</td>
 <td>Process has been interrupted by error.</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: But i need to automate the script rather than directly clicking the popup button. My problem this alert is not getting accepted/Dismissed using    IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    alert.Accept();    Also OK button is not getting recognized using selenium web driver.

Comment: You just said it is working fine :- On directly clicking OK button it is working.

Comment: that means you are able to perform actions on pop-up without any switch to alert

Comment: That I manualy clicked OK button using mouse. OK button is not getting recognized using selenium web driver so I am not able to directly click OK button using script.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refresh the page, instead of sendkey with F5 you can try as below in Java

```
 driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Regrading popup, are able to inspect elements in that popup? if you are able to inspect popup then it will be normal page not Alert.

Cross check the locator used, try with required wait to appear that ok button and is that button inside any frame or not (iframe). if it is inside frame then switch frame before click. After work is done in frame then switch back to default content.

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("provide frame name or location"); //switch to frame command

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); //switch to default content command

    //below is wait command
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id of ok")));
```

Thank You,
Murali G

Comment: It is browser popup but i am not able to locate OK button in that. When I recorded script the popup is recognized as below -  <tr>
 <td>assertAlert</td>
 <td>Process has been interrupted by error.</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: Use firebug in Firefox browser to inspect that OK button. If you are not able to inspect then it is alert. As per recording it looks like alert. But try once with firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try directly click on ok .. if still not work then check if there is any frame present .. it must a application pop-up besides browser pop-up .. switch to alert won't work in that case

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: On directly clicking OK button it is working. On recording the script the popup is recognized as -> <tr> <td>assertAlert</td> <td>Process has been interrupted by error.</td> <td></td> </tr>

Comment: you mean recording via selenium IDE

Comment: Yes. I just confirmed that this popup is web browser popup by recording using selenium IDE.